# How to get list of my databases From My SQL SERVER and add in combobox with javafx

Tags: sql-server, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I need to get a list of DataBases from my SQL Server and display all in combobox.
The combobox display a list of my databases from my SQL server, so i can select the Database that i need to open it from combobox..

Thanks for Helping me..

Comment: Generic tip of the day ::: anytime you "see" a list of things you like inside of SSMS (sql server management studio)...you can run PROFILER...wire profiler up... click "refresh" in SSMS...and see the output sql.  That will give you hints or just take the query at face value.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to query the [`sys.databases` catalog view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql), filtering on the state and whether the user has access to the database:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE
    state_desc = N'ONLINE'
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1
ORDER BY name;
```